# How to put link in css?

Tags: css

```
<style>
.button {
position: relative;
background-color: #41A0BF;
border: none;
font-size: 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 15px;
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;
text-decoration: none;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
content: "";
background: #69D2F5;
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 300%;
padding-left: 350%;
margin-left: -20px!important;
margin-top: -120%;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
opacity: 1;
transition: 0s
}
</style>
<button class="button">Home</button>
```

How to put link in button?
i tried everything codes available in google but still error in my website
i dont know whats the best code for this
thanks for someone who wants to teach me.

Answer (score 1):

No. Its not possible to add link through css. But you can use jquery

```
$('.case').each(function() {
  var link = $(this).html();
  $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="example.com/script.php?id="></a>');
});
```

Comment: How can i add that jquery in my css?

Comment: or where to put that?

Answer (score 1):

Four different possibilities to a button become a link (CSS isn't an option):

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #41A0BF;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a, a:active, a:visited, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
Javascript:<br>
<button class="button" onClick="window.location.href = 'http://example.com'">click</button><br><br>

Inner link:<br>
<button class="button"><a href="http://example.com" style="text-decoration: none">click</a></button><br><br>

Wrapper link:<br>
<a href="http://example.com"><button class="button">click</button></a><br><br>

Fake button:<br>
<a href="http://example.com" class=button>click</a>
```

Comment: but how my transition effects in this button doesnt see?

Comment: This question is about href. If you want to discuss about transitions on a button my suggestion is to open another question with this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to add anchor tag if you want to add link.

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

Add link in "#". It'll work.

Comment: but how my effects in button it doesnt see the transition

Comment: What is your exact target? Want to give link through button or anchor tag?

Comment: my exact target is to have transition effects in css button before to continue to another link but i dont know whats the best code to put link in css button.

Comment: You can try with http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/
there are lot of transition effects given for button.

Comment: i prefer with this hover button
however i dont know how to put link in button

Comment: <style>
.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #41A0BF;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {

Comment: content: "";
    background: #69D2F5;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 300%;
    padding-left: 350%;
    margin-left: -20px!important;
    margin-top: -120%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s
}

</style>

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/"><button class="button">Home</button></a>
```

Comment: but how my effects in button it doesnt see the transition

Answer (score 0):

I think its the easy way to do it.

```css
.button {
position: relative;
background-color: #41A0BF;
border: none;
font-size: 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 15px;
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;
text-decoration: none;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
content: "";
background: #69D2F5;
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 300%;
padding-left: 350%;
margin-left: -20px!important;
margin-top: -120%;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
opacity: 1;
transition: 0s
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.co.in"><button class="button">Home</button></a>
```

Comment: i tried this but my effect of transition in button doesnt see

Comment: but this link in the button it works for me but i want to see my transition effects before to continue to next page

Comment: While browsers will probably handle the markup, a button inside a link is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the link as a button this way

```
<a href="#" class="button">home</a>
```

Or if you using a css library like bootstrap

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default">home</a>
```

Comment: but how my effects in button it doesnt see the transition

Comment: The class="button" calls the css functions